# Automating a copy/paste process

Tags: vim, scripting

Can the process of going to a website, copying a page and then pasting it into an editor (which I do manually now) be done through scripts?

I use vim as my editor.  I was told you can do it using vim.  What are some keywords on this in order to find some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [netrw](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075), you can simply do `:edit <url>`. It will download the page using wget and put it in a buffer.

Comment: Thanks, CPP.  I ended up installing elinks.  Along with netrw and your suggested command, I was able to load the rendered page (not the source) and that was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the source but insert a formatted page, you can use `w3m`

```
:r!w3m -dump <url>
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I haven't looked into it yet, but it seems highly regarded as a tool.  Thanks.